# How do I retrieve an image sent in JSON to my server in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to retrieve a temporary image file sent from an app to my *PHP* script on my server. The problem is I want to take the image as declared in the path variable within the `JSON` and use it as a PHP file such as `$_FILES['picture']['name'];` just as if it was sent from a traditional web form file input.

The *PHP* code and *JSON* is below and any help is appreciated as I've been stuck on this!

**JSON:**

```
{"_origin":-112,"_subscribers":[{"version":2,"active":true}],"_isProxy":false,"_values":[{"path":"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3EF19C87-AA05-4990-883B-7F569E118105/tmp/images/IMG_4980428D-A13F-4647-98F4-D9C75232D752.jpg","name":"IMG_4980428D-A13F-4647-98F4-D9C75232D752.jpg","width":901,"height":1200,"info":{}}],"_beganSubscriptions":true}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

//Grab variables
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$title = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$market = $_POST['market'];
$account = "414890";
$date = date("Y-m-d");

//Decode JSON
$picture = json_decode($_POST['picture'], true);
$name = $picture->{'path'};

if($pass == "MY_KEY") { 

        $name = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['picture']['size'];
        $type = $_FILES['picture']['type'];

        $tmp_name = $_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'];

        $extension = substr($name, strpos($name, '.') + 1);

        $max_size = 8000000;

        //iOS Image Rotation Fix
        function correctImageOrientation($filename) {
          if (function_exists('exif_read_data')) {
            $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
            if($exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])) {
              $orientation = $exif['Orientation'];
              if($orientation != 1){
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
                $deg = 0;
                switch ($orientation) {
                  case 3:
                    $deg = 180;
                    break;
                  case 6:
                    $deg = 270;
                    break;
                  case 8:
                    $deg = 90;
                    break;
                }
                if ($deg) {
                  $img = imagerotate($img, $deg, 0);       
                }
                // then rewrite the rotated image back to the disk as $filename
                imagejpeg($img, $filename, 95);
              } // if there is some rotation necessary
            } // if have the exif orientation info
          } // if function exists     
        }

        //Unique Image Filename
        $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($tmp_name);


        //Validate and Post
        if(isset($name) && !empty($name)){
            if(($extension == "jpg" || $extension == "jpeg" || $extension == "png" || $extension == "JPG" || $extension == "PNG" || $extension == "JPEG") && $extension == $size<=$max_size){
                $location = "../member-images/";
                correctImageOrientation($tmp_name);
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$newfilename)){



                    // Insert Info into Database
                    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO voting (account, date, title, market, image) VALUES ('$account', '$date', '$title', '$market', $newfilename')");

                    /* Insert Info into Database
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO voting (account, date, title, phone, carrier, note, market, image) VALUES ('$account', '$date', '$title', '$cleaned_phone', '$carrier', '$note', '$market', '$newfilename')"); */


                }else{
                    echo 'Failed to Upload Photo. Please click back and try again.';
                }
            }else{
                echo 'File size should be no more than 100 KiloBytes & Only JPEG, JPG or PNG File. Please click back and try again.';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'Please click back and be sure to select a photo file.';
        }

        // close connection 
        $mysqli->close();


} else {

    die();

}


?>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Seems to me you're trying to access `path` in JSON, but your path is actually in `_values->path`. But there could also be other problems, please provide more details.

Comment: you are using `$name`, which comes from the `name` property in your JSON, but i think you're after `path`, since that contains the path to the image on your server. try removing this : `$name = $picture->{'path'}` and placing `$serverpath = $_FILES['picture']['type'];`, then using that in your "Validate and Post" code

Comment: I think you need some filesystem functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Comment: @godot i'm assuming for now that `move_uploaded_file` does what it says on the tin.

Comment: so what you want? you want to move "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/3EF19C87-AA05-4990-883B-7F569E118105/tmp/images/IMG_4980428D-A13F-4647-98F4-D9C75232D752.jpg" this file somewhere? (in this example)

Comment: am I right?????

Comment: For example, when someone uses the website instead of the app they complete the HTML form with a file field. It then goes into my PHP as the file field is named "upfile". As shown here...  ` $name = $_FILES['upfile']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['upfile']['size'];
$type = $_FILES['upfile']['type'];

$tmp_name = $_FILES['upfile']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: Looks to me like you're not actually sending the file to the server, you're just sending the path of the file on your mobile device to the server. Obviously (?) PHP has no way to access a file on your mobile device, whether it knows its path or not. You will have to upload the *actual file data* to PHP, whether stuffed into the JSON somehow, or as a multi-part upload, or several separate uploads.

Comment: I can do two separate uploads but not sure how to connect each of them server side?